# Button not displayed on emulator or on Device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-view, android-button

I am a beginner on Android. I have created 2 activities. First activity has 1 button (say `Button1`) and 1 `TextView` (say `TextView1`) and the Second activity has 1 `TextView` (say `TextView2`). The text value for `TextView` in 1st activity is "Hello World!", when the `Button1` is pressed opens up 2nd `Activity` passing the value of the `TextView1` (i.e. "Hell World!"). The 2nd `Activity` assigns the obtained value to the `TextView2` and displays.

All of this is working fine.

When I add a new `Button` (say `Button2`) to the 1st activity and write a `onClick()` method to change the text of `TextView1` from "Hello World!" to "Hello Android!" and vice versa. Now when I run this on my device or emulator I cannot see this added button (`Button2`) it still works as earlier when I click `Button1`, but I cannot see `Button2`.

Can anyone help me on this ?

> XML Layout : MainActivity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ourButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginRight="37dp"
    android:onClick="buttonClick"
    android:text="@string/button_string" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ourButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:onClick="buttonClick2"
    android:text="@string/button_string2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant layout and code in the question.

Comment: please post xml layout of before/after you add the second button

Comment: Here is the XML layout of the 1st Activity (main Activity)

Comment: ur both buttons are overlaping

Comment: The difference in before/after adding the button is just the addition of the 2nd <Button> tag in the above XML Layout.

Comment: Both buttons are ovelapping ?? But the Alignment of them is different with respect to the TextView. Button1 : android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView" and Button2 : 
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have `android:layout_below="@+id/textView"` twice. Try this instead:

```
<!-- below the previous view : ourButton -->
<Button
android:id="@+id/ourButton2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textView"
android:layout_below="@id/ourButton"
android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
android:focusable="false"
android:onClick="buttonClick2"
android:text="@string/button_string2" />
```

Also, don't use `@+id/` for align your layout. You use it right when you add an `id` but when the `id` is created, you just have to align on it as `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/prevId"` with `@id`.

---

*Example:*

Here the layout:

```
                         |---- text -----|
                                           <- both are below text
                         |---- view1 ----|| <- view align right
     view align left -> ||---- view2 ----|
```

As you can see, the left and right alignment are on the "border" of the TextView because you set an alignment **below** the TextView. So it looks like this:

```
                       |------ text ------|
                                           <- both are below text
  view1 align left -> ||---- view 1&2 ----|| <- view2 align right
```

Your views are overlapping each other. If you want to have the two buttons below the text and side by side, try to add a container, like this following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ourButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:onClick="buttonClick"
            android:text="@string/button_string" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ourButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="buttonClick2"
            android:text="@string/button_string2" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did the following changes I can see that positioning of the 2nd button Below TextView and left to Button1 in the graphical Display...but when I tun it on Device I can just see Button1    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ourButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ourButton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:onClick="buttonClick2"
        android:text="@string/button_string2" />

Comment: I have tried few more changes and plaed this Button2 above the TextView now. I can see the changes in position of the Button2 on Graphical Layout on Eclipse. But when I run it on device I am getting the app like it used to be before adding the Button2 (i.e. TextVeiew and Button1 below it)

Comment: If you want the buttons side by side, try to add a container like LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc. Try my example to see if that changed.

Comment: @Gabriel another thing that can disturbe your layout is the *centerHorizontal* & *centerVertical* of the TextView. If you need to center the child views, you should make the **gravity** of RelativeLayout to *center*. Let me know if you have the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to remove

```
    android:layout_marginRight="37dp"
```

and then try. Are you able to see output on xml graphical layout ? When I tried this on my xml I am able to see in Graphical Layout(I used the same code which you mentioned along with your question).

Answer (score 1):

```
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
         android:id="@+id/ourButton"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
         android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
         android:layout_marginRight="37dp"
         android:onClick="buttonClick"
         android:text="@string/button_string" />

    <Button
         android:id="@+id/ourButton2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/ourButton"
         android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
         android:focusable="false"
         android:onClick="buttonClick2"
         android:text="@string/button_string2" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ourButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="buttonClick"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_string" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ourButton2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:onClick="buttonClick2"
        android:text="@string/button_string2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```